# Triple (n-state) variable toggle in vim

Tags: vim

What's the best way to do triple state toggling in vim?
Can I do something like? (C):

```
void toggle(void)
{
    static int var = 3-1;
    var=(var+1)%3;
    printf("%d\n", var);
}
int main()
{
    toggle(); //0
    toggle(); //1
    toggle(); //2
    toggle(); //0
    toggle(); //1
    toggle(); //2

}
```

I tried

```
fun! Toggle()
    let l:var=0
    let l:var+=1
    echom l:var
endfun
```

But this always prints 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable is local (hence the `l` in `l:var`) and so every time you call `Toggle()` it "resets itself" to zero. You can use a global variable by using the prefix `g`.

```
let g:var=0
fun! Toggle()
    let g:var = (g:var + 1) % 3
    echom g:var
endfun
```

And then inside vim:

```
:call Toggle()
0
:call Toggle()
1
:call Toggle()
2
:call Toggle()
0
```

I'd recommend prefixing your global variable with some identifier (e.g. `let g:pskocik_toggle_count`) to prevent collisions with plugins and other scripts.

Answer (score 0):

The closest equivalent to C static variables are the script local s:variables. As the name suggests, they are not local to functions but to scripts.

On a side note, I provide a function for this purpose in my library plugin: [`lh#menu#def_toggle_item()`](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/doc/lh-vim-lib.txt#L2562).

My associated unit tests are [over there](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/tests/lh/test-toggle-menu.vim).

What it does:

- It permits to cycle through a series of possible values thanks to `:Toggle MenuSubmenuVariable [value]` -- completion is supported
- works with text and numeric value
- hook/action can be associated when changing state, or when going into a new state
- a menu is also produced to change the state of the variable
- it will update a variable that can be manipulated by the end user

For instance, this is a complex example which triggers events:

```
let Data4 = {
      \ "variable": "yesno",
      \ "values": [ 1, 2, 3 ],
      \ "text": [ "No", "Yes", "Perhaps" ],
      \ "actions": [ function("s:No"), function("s:Yes"), function('s:Perhaps') ],
      \ "menu": { "priority": '42.50.20', "name": '&LH-Tests.&TogMenu.&yesno'}
      \}
call lh#menu#def_toggle_item(Data4)
```

which permits to toggle/cycle with:

```
:Toggle LHTestsTogMenuyesno    " to go to the next state
:Toggle LHTestsTogMenuyesno no " to force a value
:echo g:yesno                  " -> 1 (associated to "no")
```